# Примеры SVG графики как в MS Excel

Tags: svg, html, css

Всем доброго дня.

Представьте себе диаграммы, как в ms excel, круговые (особенно интересуют), точечные, столбики. Возможно ли сделать данное безобразие на SVG? Есть ли ресурсы какие для совсем лентяев (аналогичные как для построения фонов, теней и градиентов)?

В основном натыкаюсь на примеры с подключением дополнительных библиотек, что замедляет web страницу. Есть ли примеры без них?

P.S. [Вот примерно такое на SVG найти не смог](http://netcoding.ru/files/articles/mini/risuem-diagrammu-s-pomoshyu-google-charts.jpg).

Comment: Мой вам совет - не дурите голову, воспользуйтесь чем-нибудь вроде этого: http://www.flotcharts.org/ или этого http://www.chartjs.org/ Зачем изобретать велосипед? Вам все равно придется писать какую-никакую библиотеку, которая все так же начнет грузить страницу. И не факт, что меньше, чем эти эти библиотеки.

Comment: я бы и взял готовый велосипед, так ведь нету! простые плоские SVG картинки - пожалуйста, а вот что то, с хотя бы намеком на объем - нету

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-column-interactive

Но ведь не трендово. )

Comment: Оно! Ответ, прошу из комментариев в ответы перекинуть, для акцепта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот этот плагин: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-column-interactive